# Can't get pidgin to work or install on 16.10

Tags: 16.10, pidgin

Hey I'm new from windows.

I'm on 16.10 and at first I tried installing the pidgin version that is in the software center but when I try to open it nothing happened.  When I run it from terminal I would get this error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

So I tried running `sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0`  and got

```
Package libgstreamer0.10-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgstreamer0.10-0' has no installation candidate
```

I thought maybe I should try installing the newest pidgin from their site following this guide https://www.linuxbabe.com/instant-messenger/compile-install-pidgin-2-11-0-ubuntu-16-04

but when I get to the part to install the dependencies I got

```
E: Unable to locate package libgstreamer0.10-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgstreamer0.10-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgstreamer0.10-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libfarstream-0.1-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libfarstream-0.1-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libfarstream-0.1-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev'
```

I tried searching synaptic but nothing comes up for any of these packs. Can anyone help me figure out how to get pidgin working please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try installing the missing packages manually from the 16.04 versions. Here are links for

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgstreamer0.10-dev
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
- and the same link base for libfarstream-0.1-dev

Upper right corner to select Ubuntu version (xenial = 16.04).
You can get your architecture with

```
uname -a
```

to determine which architecture version to download.
Install downloaded packages with

```
sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE_FILE_LOCATION.deb
```